# How to limit AWS Route 53 query frequency?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

We have activated "Route53 public DNS query logging" but have not found a way to limit DNS lookups (A, AAAA). Is there a way with the AWS CLI to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you trying to limit the DNS queries from your domain's users? If yes, that is not an option that is available. You could however adjust the TTL values to make them stay longer in DNS resolver's cache thus reducing the need to query. Do note that for a change in IP might take the time mentioned in TTL to be fully propagated. So you will have to set TTL to a value "not too high"